How to save Mardia's coefficient of skewness in a vector when the data is divided into 4 parts
Minimum Working Example:
##############################################################################
set.seed(10)
##############################################################################
library(Matrix)
library(psych)
##############################################################################
N0 <- 1
n0 <- 5
p0 <- 2
q0 <- 4
n  <- n0*q0
##############################################################################
m2 <- matrix(c(0,0),p0,1)
s2 <- matrix(c(1,0,0,1),p0,p0)
##############################################################################
Dat     <- array(data=NA,dim=c(n0,p0,q0,N0))
m1 <- array(data=NA,dim=c(q0,1,1))
#MNA<-array(data=NA,dim=c(q0,1,1))
for (i in 1:N0){
for (j in 1:q0){
            Dat[,,j,i]      <- mvrnorm(n=n0,m2,s2)
            MNA[,,j,i]<-   mardia(Dat[,,j,i],plot=FALSE)
            m1<-MNA$b1p
                     
}
}
I

want to ask that how to get a vector named MNA in which all of my 4 skewness coefficients will be shown.
because when i write MNA in R it only gives the skewness coefficient of the last data piece.
MNA<- mardia(x = Dat[, , j, i], plot = FALSE)

Mardia tests of multivariate skew and kurtosis
Use describe(x) the to get univariate tests
n.obs = 5   num.vars =  2 
b1p =  1.12   skew =  0.93  with probability  <=  0.92
 small sample skew =  2.23  with probability <=  0.69
b2p =  3.35   kurtosis =  -1.3  with probability <=  0.19> 
I

only get result of the last piece of data.
I'm expecting to get a vector named MNA in which all the 4 skewness vectors are presented.

Welcome to Stackoverflow. I'm likely thinking about this wrong, but N0 = 1,  and i in 1:N0 would suggest 1 (mardia result list) , rather than 4. Perhaps i in 1:q0 and j in 1:NO?

So there is a further call to extract the desired values from mardia_lst, the_bp1 <-  unlist(unname(c(mardia_lst[[1]][3], mardia_lst[[2]][3], mardia_lst[[3]][3], mardia_lst[[4]][3]))) [1] 0.5932328 1.7587304 0.7904464 1.3511906 perhaps?

I made the suggested changes and got this error. Error in [<-(tmp, , , j, i, value = MASS::mvrnorm(n = n0, m2, s2)) :  subscript out of bounds

I got the same error when using MNA as receiver. mardia produces a list output, so best to send it to an empty list, <- list(). If you str(mardia_lst[[1]]), what jumps to mind for dim values for MNA[here, and_here, ?, should MNA be MNA[12, j, i]? I don't know off hand but still want bp1, thus elected empty list with further extraction. Given how MNA is defined, with # MNA[4, ,j,i] (q0), (error MNA not found as not defined outside loop, and when defined was wrong dim) it was inevitable to fail on dimensions when 12 something are coming. Tried it your way, had to change course.

Changing your approach somewhat, using your parameters and matrix members as above, but in places replacing variables with values to better see what dimensions are:
library(Matrix)
library(psych)
library(MASS) # for mvrnorm()

set.seed(10)
N0 <- 1
n0 <- 5
p0 <- 2
q0 <- 4
n  <- n0*q0 # this was calculated for a reason, not used above
m2 <- matrix(c(0,0),p0,1)
dim(m2)
[1] 2 1
s2 <- matrix(c(1,0,0,1),p0,p0)
dim(s2)
[1] 2 2
dim(mvrnorm(n=n, m2, s2)) # using n, and we want 4 samples, 1 for loop
[1] 20  2
# implies dim(Dat) 20, 2, 4
Dat <- array(data = NA, dim = c(20, 2, 4) # being: n, p0, q0
mardia_lst_vec <- vector('list', length = 4L) 

for (i in 1:q0) {
  Dat[,,i] <- MASS::mvrnorm(n = n, m2, s2)
  mardia_lst_vec[[i]] <- mardia(Dat[,,i], plot = FALSE)
  }

the_bp1 <- unlist(unname(c(mardia_lst_vec[[1]][3], mardia_lst_vec[[2]][3], mardia_lst_vec[[3]][3], mardia_lst_vec[[4]][3])))

the_bp1
[1] 2.00642974 1.82069395 1.98683385 0.07528788


Perhaps this may be closer to what you are looking for.
